# How can I add all values in a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there a simple way of getting the total price of all the fruits in a list of dictionaries in Python?

```
[{'name':'apple','price':10},{'name':'banana','price':5},{'name':'grapes','price':15}]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the following line:

```
sum(item['price'] for item in list)
```

Comment: `sum(item['price'] for item in list)` will work without having to create a list.